Any updates on "The minimum cost perfect matching problem with conflict pair constraints"?
The subject of the paywalled article The minimum cost perfect matching problem with conflict pair constraints (MCPMPC) are perfect matchings of minimum cost that do not contain certain pairs of edges; that problem is stated to be strongly NP-hard.
It doesn't take much imagination to see the striking analogy to the problem of finding cycle covers without short cycles in directed graphs; the forbidden pairs are antiparallel arcs in this case and its decision variant is NP-complete.
Questions:

where is the NP-hardness of MCPMPC established
are there any updates on the problem in the sense of generalisations or better (in whatever sense) approximation algorithms
has the applicability to directed cycle covers via optimal assignment in the biadjacency matrix already been noticed


It says that the NP-hardness of MCPMPC is proven here:
"Paths, trees and matchings under disjunctive constraints" by Darmann, Pferschy, Schauer and Woeginger.
